# Could we have an option to search for questions with a bounty?

Tags: feature-request, bounty, search

Going through the [featured questions](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) page to see the bounties that are open, I was wondering if any of them have some tags I am familiar with. I tried to use `[bash] bounty:yes` in the Search form but this did not work.

Checking the [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) page I confirmed there is not such option and I wondered: wouldn't it be nice to have it, so that we can easily look for such questions together with other conditions?

My current way to see if there is any open bounty on some tags I follow is to enter in something like `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag1+or+tag2+or...` and then click "featured". But it is a bit long to do and, still, it does not allow further filtering.

Comment: Not a great solution, but questions tagged with your favourite tags will be highlighted, yes?

Comment: What's wrong with clicking on your favorite tag then selecting "featured"? And actually, now with the new layout (if you are using it) there is a "bounties" tab

Comment: The new navigation actually has this: Once you're looking at bounties you can filter by your favorite tags or custom tags. So this is a feature they're already working on.

Comment: @codeMagic uhms, cool. I activated the new layout but I wasn't picked, so I cannot see it.

Comment: Ok, but my first suggestion still would work, no? That's what I've done in the past

Comment: True, it doesn't help you now but I figured since this was tagged feature-request I'd mention that it's in the works.

Comment: @codeMagic it works for the basic case: get just the featured in this tag. But since the list can be long, it may be interesting to say `[php] bounty:yes "date"` or similar. That is, to look for bounties in the [php] tag having `date` as text.

Comment: Ah, yes, missed a part of your question. Carry on...

Comment: @fedorqui @frédérichamidi @onebree Can we add an advance search attribute `bounty:100` that would function just like the `score:3` attribute?

Comment: @sdc this would be a very good idea!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I opted in for the alpha navigation throughout Stack Exchange. I attached a screenshot of the navigation. I think it may solve your question.

[image: 2015-0626_alpha_navbar]

If you click on the Bounties label, a filter is applied (same as clicking "need answers"). You can also look for bounties associated with your favorite tags by clicking on the tag, followed by clicking on "need answers" or the Bounties label.

I hope this helps. I do not know when the next wave of alpha releases will be, but this is a very convenient new feature.

**EDIT**: You can also filter by all, favorite, or custom tags (1 or more), as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The address  for this search is [/?tab=needanswer&show=bounties&tagFilter=recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=needanswer&show=bounties&tagFilter=recommended), in case that works for people not testing the new layout.

Comment: @nallar thank you -- I added your comment to my answer.

Comment: That query doesn't work. For those of us not on the new layout, that page just doesn't exist.

Comment: @Kendra I am going to remove the query, and let people just read the comments then.

Comment: Great, finally I got to see this new layout : )

Comment: how do we get on the new layout? it is several years later and there seems to be no (intuitive) way to find questions with bounties.

Answer (score 37):

Since starting a bounty adds a notice to the question, it is possible to abuse the `hasnotice` operator to achieve what you want.

For instance, the following search:

`[bash] hasnotice:yes closed:no duplicate:no locked:no migrated:no`

(https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[bash]+hasnotice%3Ayes+closed%3Ano+duplicate%3Ano+locked%3Ano+migrated%3Ano)

Returns all the questions tagged `[bash]` that have a bounty (right now there is only one).

Comment: Beautiful! This is a nice workaround : )

Comment: Note I am not accepting the answer because it is a feature request not to have to abuse the `hasnotice`. I will use this solution in the meantime, though. Thanks!

Comment: @fedorqui, no problem at all, let's see what comes out of this.

Comment: Uhms, weird: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[linux]+hasnotice%3Ayes+closed%3Ano+duplicate%3Ano+locked%3Ano+migrated%3Ano (the same with [linux] instead of [bash]) returns some [a migrated question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/32884) and [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30869945/1983854) whose bounty was already awarded.

Comment: Interesting indeed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30869945/how-to-import-lldb-in-a-python-script does not seem to have any visible notice, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935784/why-does-the-sd-card-random-write-performance-for-record-size-8-128-kb-drops-bel should not match `migrated:no`. So this is not a foolproof solution (then again, these two occurrences look like bugs).

Comment: Aaah the problem was with caching. In the first one the bounty was awarded not very long ago: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30869945/revisions (25 minutes now). And the second one was migrated 40 minutes ago: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/32884/revisions

Comment: Ah, nice catch :) That should settle with time, then.

Comment: This matches questions with a custom notice like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30008114/1529630).

Comment: @Oriol, true, this is the *Insufficient explanation* notice, which I've never seen before. To my knowledge, there is no way to exclude it from searches, so these questions will match indeed.

Comment: Nice, but for some reason gives some quirky results.  For example, replace [bash] with [java], and you get a list of questions, most of which have bounties, but at least this one has no bounty and was migrated:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866417/please-correct-for-loop-design?s=2|3.3208