# How can I search for bounty questions with 0 answers?

Tags: support, bounty

I can search for awarding bounty questions with android tags using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android/?tab=featured/unanswered), but it won't return unanswered ones. Is there anyway we can do it?

Comment: You can try `[tag] is:q hasnotice:yes closed:no migrated:no answers:0` but note that there might be some posts with notices that aren't bountied. See the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for more.

Comment: @ryanyuyu You can get to the help page for searching by just making a search and going through the advanced tips on the side, by the way. No need to rely on the help center search.

Comment: Funny how this search command returns only duplicates

Comment: I actually missed a parameter. The real query would be `[tag] is:q hasnotice:yes closed:no migrated:no locked:no answers:0` See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297766/could-we-have-an-option-to-search-for-questions-with-a-bounty

Comment: @Kendra, @Holmes, @jameswebster  Can we add an advance search attribute `bounty:100` that would function just like the `score:3` attribute?

Comment: @sdc That sounds like a feature request- Search here and MSE for duplicates, then if you don't find any to support, feel free to post it as such! Be sure to explain why you feel it would be useful and helpful for the community.

Comment: @Kendra - I found this [post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297766/could-we-have-an-option-to-search-for-questions-with-a-bounty). Should we close this question as a duplicate?

Comment: @sdc They aren't the same question- This one was asking how it can be done with the current system. That one was asking for a change to the system.

Comment: @kendra can you post your comment as an answer and Holmes can accept it