# When does a bountied question lose its notice?

Tags: bug, bounty, search

There is a feature request for an option to search for bountied questions:

- [Could we have an option to search for questions with a bounty?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297766/could-we-have-an-option-to-search-for-questions-with-a-bounty)

As one possible work-around, it is suggested that the `hasnotice` option can be abused for this purpose. This is not perfect (as many have noted), because a bounty is not the only kind of notice a question may have. Also, bounties are obviously not permanent, and there may be a delay in removing their notices.

But my question is: how long is this delay? As an example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39614777/984421) had a bounty set on 23 Sept 2016, which then lapsed with no answers. However, a search with [[pyqt] hasnotice:yes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyqt%5D+hasnotice%3Ayes) is still listing it as of 19 Oct 2016, and there do not appear to be any other notices on the question.

**UPDATE**:

As of 24 October 2016, the linked question is no longer listed as having a notice, which seemed to coincide with someone posting an answer for it.

Comment: Wow, that is some serious caching.  The timeline says the notice was removed on 2016-10-01 12:57:35Z

Comment: That would be a bug in the search not updating its results correctly. The notice gets removed within a couple hours of the grace period expiring.

Comment: @animuson. Should I re-tag this as a bug, then?

Comment: Why do this the hard way?  Click the [tag] then click the Featured tab.

Comment: @HansPassant. That's not what my question is about. But anyway: as stated in the linked question, it allows searching for bounties to be combined with other search condtions.

Comment: It is what the solution is about.  Questions often have very flawed assumptions, such as expecting to ever have to filter bounties on more than just a [tag].

Comment: @HansPassant. I simply expect to be able to use the `hasnotice` search option to find questions with notices. How is that a flawed assumption?